# How to tell if datagram packet arrived without calling receive?

Tags: java

I'm using UDP for the first time and I'm wondering if there is a way to find out if a packet has arrived without calling receive on a Java 7 `DatagramSocket`.

I'm trying to set up my client so that it can send multiple packets to a server and after each packet sent, check to see if a response has come in from the server.

Right now I am just using the `setSoTimeout` method on the `DatagramSocket` to set the timeout to 1 milisecond, but I would rather not wait at all if it is possible.

Update:

I ended up learning about the java.nio package and was able to use that nonblocking api to do this.

Comment: Whаt's wrong with receive? Set datagram socket in blocking mode, and receive would return as soon as data arrive.

Comment: Remember that UDP is "best effort" delivery only.  Packets don't even have to be delivered in the order sent.  If your packets don't contain sequence numbers so you can match outgoing packets with responses then you will get hopelessly muddled with one dropped packet or reversed order.

Comment: Yes I understand what UDP is. I'm just wondering if there is a way to know if a packet has arrived without blocking to find out. I'd like to be able to call receive (or some other method) without it blocking if it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope it's alright to answer my own question - but I ended up learning about the [java.nio](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html) package. This is a non blocking socket api.

Comment: Not only is it alright, but [it is encouraged.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16933/175248)

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing. How did you use the java.nio package to do this?

Comment: What class did you actually use? Pointing to an entire package is not particularly helpful.